# Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to send data to the router from an external script and it returns the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

Here is the code

**app.js**

```
var Cake = require('./modules/cake');

router.get('/cakes', function(req, res) {
  Cake.getCake();
})
```

**cake.js**

```
module.exports = {
  getCake: function (req, res) {
    request({
      url: "http://get.cakes/json",
      json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        res.send(body);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Take note that `http://get.cake/` isn't a real site. It's irrelevent to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not passing `req` and `res` down to `getCake`

```
router.get('/cakes', function(req, res) {
  Cake.getCake(); // <-- you're passing nothing here so `res` is undefined within `getCake` and so you're calling `undefined.send()`
})
```

You should have:

```
router.get('/cakes', function(req, res) {
  Cake.getCake(req, res); // <-- pass `req` and `res` down to `getCake`
})
```

Or even shorthand:

```
router.get('/cakes', Cake.getCake);
```

Comment: So I should add the req, res in the `getCake: function ()`?

Comment: not sure what you mean, you already did that. `getCake` is defined as `getCake: function (req, res) { ... }`

Comment: Ignore that last comment but thank you for that, it worked! I'll accept your answer after the 15 minute cooldown. :)